# jQuery modal dialog cancel button isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery modal dialog in my web application. I have used one `button (cancel)` and want to close dialog by clicking on it but it's not working, while `disable & destroy` is working.
any idea please....

***Code :***

```
$("#dialog-form" ).dialog({
          ....
         buttons: {
             Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );  // dialog doesn't close

         //   $( this ).dialog( "destroy" ); (it's working)
         //   $( this ).dialog( "disable" ); (it's working)
 }
```

Comment: you missed at least 3 brackets or just not posted the whole code

Comment: yes didn't post the whole code. i wanted to show how i have written the code i.e. not working

Comment: Your code has no problem. Maybe it is related to your ui.js version. Upgrade to the last version and i suggest that it will work by 99%. ;)

Comment: ok, let me try but why only "close" is not working while others are working. thanks

Comment: @rahim: yes, you are right but not sure how to correct it. when i link the js file with **http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/..** it works but the same file linked locally doesn't work. Can you help me out on this

Comment: Download the latest ui library from here: http://jqueryui.com/download. and it will work.

Comment: I just managed to to solve this issue by changing the js file. I was getting error due js file which was linked with local server.

I linked the js file with following url and finally it worked for me

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js


http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized now, it was my silly question but i hope it'd be helpful to someone. The problem i was getting due to missing of several files.e.g : There is a CSS file eithier we can use by linking directly or just download the file and put it in your web application and then link to your own server.

**solution 1** :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/ui.all.css"/>
```

***solotion 2 :***  just download the css file and put it in your server. as i downloaded a css file called `jquery.ui.all.css`and put this inside of my `webApplication/lib`. Now i can linked

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my_web_app/lib/jquery.ui.all.css"/>
```

but here is a big deal, you need to check the file if it is importing some other files or not, as i went through this file and found that it is importing two other files.

```
@import "jquery.ui.base.css";
@import "jquery.ui.theme.css";
```

This is what i was making mistake, again i downloaded these two files separately and put it in the same folder of my web app (my_web-App/lib/.....).

**Problem due to jQuery file :** make sure you always use the updated version of jQuery file. This is where i got stuck but finally i found that i am using the old version (`jQuery v1.3.2`) of jQuery file while i was needed latest one (`jQuery v1.6.2`).